# How to parse an array of data in PHP separated by a semicolon and display each section as a new line on an HTML page?

Tags: php, arrays, string

What I got is an array coming as in the format below.
What I would need to do is to print each block of string, separated by an ";" to a new line on an html page.

For example, the two lines below would be printed after processing the array below them.

```
Tesla motors : 60%
Mercedes Benz : 40%
```

How to split this data to an array, which could then be looped thru and display each one on page? The separator here is ";" semicolon.

Thank you so much already in advance!
Yours,

```
array (
  0 => 'T',
  1 => 'e', 
  2 => 's', 
  3 => 'l', 
  4 => 'a', 
  5 => ' ', 
  6 => 'm', 
  7 => 'o', 
  8 => 't', 
  9 => 'o', 
  10 => 'r', 
  11 => 's', 
  45 => ' ', 
  46 => ':', 
  47 => ' ',
  48 => '60', 
  49 => '%', 
  50 => ';'
  53 => 'M',
  53 => 'e',  
  53 => 'r',
  54 => 'c',
  55 => 'e',
  56 => 'd',
  57 => 'e',
  58 => 's',
  59 => ' ',
  60 => 'B',
  61 => 'e',
  62 => 'n',
  63 => 'z',
  94 => ' ',
  95 => ':',
  96 => ' ',
  97 => '4',
  98 => '0',
  99 => '%',
  100 => ';'
)
```

Comment: `explode(';', implode('', $arr))`

Comment: Wrapping @splash58 answer in array_filter() will remove the empty item at the end... `array_filter(explode(';', implode('', $foo)))`

Comment: Thank you I got my problem solved with all your help here!

Answer (score 0):

First you should use [implode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) to with empty string as glue parameter.

This will transform your array into an string:

```
Tesla motors : 60%;Mercedes Benz : 40%
```

Now you can either use [explode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) to get an array with one row for each line:

```
$output = explode(";", implode('', $input));
```

Or you can replace the `;` by a new line character:

```
$output = str_replace(";", "\n", implode('', $input));
```

Comment: Thank you I got my problem solved with all your help here!